# Swagger response with both a file and object data

Tags: swagger-2.0

I have a Swagger file where I am trying to return both a file (a .png image) and other data with the image (defined as an object)
This is what my yaml file looks like currently, with only the object being returned with the 200 response code:

```
 get:
  summary: Get Practice Information
  description: |
    This call will return information about a specific Practice.
  tags:
  - Practice
  parameters:
  - name: apikey
    in: query
    description: apikey
    required: true
    type: string
  - name: PracticeName
    in: query
    description: Name of Practice
    required: true
    type: string
  responses:
    200:
      description: Information about a Practice
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/PracticeInfo'
    400:
      description: Application error
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/ApplicationError'
    500:
      description: System error
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/SystemError'
```

I've tried putting "type: File" in various places with no luck. I tried putting the File in the object itself and that didn't work either. I could make it only return an image with:

```
responses:
    200:
      description: Information about a Practice
      schema:
        type: file
        description: Logo
```

But I cannot seem to do both at once. Form-data works for parameter input, but I don't see how to do this in a response.